# Converting a string to dictionary easily

Tags: python

I have a string:

```
my_str =  '{"country":{"AE":"United Arab Emirates","AL":"Albania","AM":"Armenia","AR":"Argentina","AT":"Austria","AU":"Australia","AW":"Aruba"}}'
```

Is there an easy way to convert it into dictionary? I'd like to use something like `dict(my_str)` but it doesn't exist.

Easy way.

Comment: `my_dict = ast.literal_eval(my_str)`

Comment: @khelwood You're right.

Comment: @khelwood:  If possible; you should use `json` instead of `ast.literal_eval()`: `my_dict = json.loads(my_str)` (do not use Python syntax if the *much* *much* simpler format will do).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, this is one way only from many ways

```
json.loads(my_str)
```